# how to stop a spring writer in one job exectuion

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I use spring batch to import data from redis to DB every 5 minute and here is what i do。

I write a redis reader，reader all the key I want in one time using the redis.keys command, than I transport these keys to a jdbc writer.

The problem is, once the job has been started, the reader will run continuous，but I only want execute the redis.keys command one time in one batch job run.
Does any one know how to accomplish this?

---

update thx @Michael Minella
I implement the ItemStreamReader interface, of which the open() method will be executed only once before a job step start. Besides, I also implement the ItemListenerSupport interface, of which the afterRead() method will be executed everytime after the read() method. So in the open() method, I retrieve the data from the redis, put it in a map, return the map in the read() and set the map to null in the afterRead(). So next time when the read() is executed, it will return null which indicates the job will complete.
But it is kinda of tricky, maybe spring-batch could add an Reader Interface which run only once in each job instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Batch `ItemReaders` and `ItemWriters` can also extend an additional interface called `ItemStream`.  This interface provides some additional life cycle methods that are useful for this scenario.  In your case, I'd recommend doing the actual read in the `ItemStream.open` method.  This is called once at the beginning of the step.  Then, in the `ItemReader.read` method, you can iterate through the results of the query.  There are a number of `ItemReader` implementations provided with Spring Batch that use this technique.  One example is the `JdbcCursorItemReader` who's source code can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.java